# Response time of wp rest api is too much

Tags: wordpress, api, performance-testing, restful-architecture, wordpress-rest-api

I have my WordPress website is running on digital ocean server with NGINX web server and an app server running on another digital ocean server with NGINX web server. An app server is where my rest api is running. In my api I'm retrieving some data from WordPress rest api according to requests. While testing my api performance my api response is too much for route in which I'm fetching data from wordpress rest api. I'm using siege for performance testing here :

[image: My one of testing result]

How can optimize my api for better response. On which side I have to make change either on my wordpress site or app server side.?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to get the reason for the slow response times, it might be due to:

- server is overloaded - to check it use monitoring tools like [top](https://linux.die.net/man/1/top), [vmstat](http://www.linuxcommand.org/man_pages/vmstat8.html), [sar](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sar), etc.
- configuration of Nginx, out of the box it may be not ready for the maximum performance and you will need to [do some tuning](https://www.nginx.com/blog/tuning-nginx/)
- your application code is the bottleneck, in that case use [Wordpress profiling tool](https://wordpress.org/plugins/p3-profiler/) to determine the reason of the slow responses

Also you can consider using [Taurus](http://gettaurus.org/) tool as a wrapper for your Siege script, it provides [Siege Executor](http://gettaurus.org/docs/Siege/), this way you will be able to see some extended reports and correlate the increasing load with the increasing response time.